# Close proecssors after thread completed

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Is there a way of closing a thread after it finishes?

For example, i currently have:

```
 pool = mp.Pool(processes=6)
 all_items = [pool.apply_async(function_name, args=(task)) for task in all_tasks]
 for item in all_items:
    item.get()  
 pool.close()
```

The threads are only closed after all 6 have finished. Is it possible to close them individually after they are each done. (i.e., to free up RAM that is getting tied up by the completed proecsses)

Comment: Threads finish by default after they done. There isn't need to do anything.